# how to parse url in android

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

I have an URL that should parse the value but when I give

```
private static String url = "http://54.174.74.84/api/index/index?data={%20%22language_code%22:%22en_us%22,%20%22cmd%22:%22search_projects%22,%20%22user_device_id%22:319,%20%22page%22:0,%20%22user_token%22:%22edeN2y0EuakoD2deWGzijeuBQ5HRnhokyAqV4WIHzZz5PM0Qn2xgopKiAcboNJktgXeQMsX7kZmDW3T5Tta3i+Fz1mU5p1yTP1L3m\/OTGkOlDoJrLn6\/+I3rBqESDtFH%22,%20%22source_app%22:%22android%22,%20%22longitude%22:%22567%22,%20%22user_id%22:67,%20%22latitude%22:%22123%22,%20%22records_per_page%22:%2210%22,%20%22search_key%22:%22%22%20}";
```

like this it is showing error. So please help me. Thanks.

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `Uri` class:

```
String uri = Uri.parse("http://54.174.74.84/api/index/index")
            .buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter("data", "{%20%22language_ ..... %22%22%20}")
            .appendQueryParameter("param2", value2)
            .appendQueryParameter("param3", value3)
            .build().toString();
```

Comment: tnx.i will try an get back u

Comment: if by "different keys" you mean different URL parameters, then you need to append them by calling `appendQueryParameter()` again and again for each parameter, see edited answer :)

Comment: i dont konw how to parse the code.becoz i am beginer.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/                 and im following this example

Comment: create a new question and post the link here :)

Comment: u can parse it using post man know.so plz parse it and say how to keep it to list view.i need to set title ,start.location,description only in it.it has many  keys and value pair.

Comment: post a new question with ALL the details and add the link here, then I will take a look at it :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error. Just string encoding with java encoder class. You have to just decode string before using it like below code...

```
String url = "http://54.174.74.84/api/index/index?data={%20%22language_code%22:%22en_us%22,%20%22cmd%22:%22search_projects%22,%20%22user_device_id%22:319,%20%22page%22:0,%20%22user_token%22:%22edeN2y0EuakoD2deWGzijeuBQ5HRnhokyAqV4WIHzZz5PM0Qn2xgopKiAcboNJktgXeQMsX7kZmDW3T5Tta3i+Fz1mU5p1yTP1L3m/OTGkOlDoJrLn6/+I3rBqESDtFH%22,%20%22source_app%22:%22android%22,%20%22longitude%22:%22567%22,%20%22user_id%22:67,%20%22latitude%22:%22123%22,%20%22records_per_page%22:%2210%22,%20%22search_key%22:%22%22%20}";

String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
```